# In Multiline JSX when to use parentheses, when to use fragments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When declaring a javascript variable with multiline JSX elements I get same output when using fragments and also parentheses in React.js, not sure what could be the difference between these two and when to use

```
//When using multi line JSX with fragments

const MultiElementWithFragments = 
<>
  <div>
    This is test 1
    <div>
      This is test 2
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div>
    This is test 3
  </div>
</>

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

function tick() {
  root.render(<>{MultiElementWithFragments}</>)
}
tick();
```

```
//When using multi line JSX with fragments

const MultiElementWithParentheses = (
<>
  <div>
    This is test 1
    <div>
      This is test 2
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div>
    This is test 3
  </div>
</>
)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

function tick() {
  root.render(<>{MultiElementWithParentheses}</>)
}
tick();
```

From the above two codes, both of them are producing same output

[image: Output]

Comment: There is no difference; in that particular example, the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: So that means we can use fragments in all multi line JSX statements without adding fragments or is there any specific scenario where fragments doesn't work but it works parentheses

Answer (score 2):

The following is bad, for several reasons:

```
const multiBAD =
  <div/>
  <div/>
```

Let's talk first about the seemingly identical

```
const multiBADInOneLine = <div/><div/>
```

The first reason is simply — you can't put two values in a variable. You can put two values in a list, or an object, or a fragment, then assign that *one* thing to a variable:

```
const multiList = [
  <div/>,
  <div/>,
]

const multiObject = {
  first: <div/>,
  second: <div/>,
]

const multiFragment = <>
  <div/>
  <div/>
</>
```

But the original multiline bad code above will not actually give you an error, because of the second reason: ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion). JavaScript will end the statement as soon as the code makes sense. So,

```
const multiBAD =
  <div/>
  <div/>
```

will actually compile as

```
const multiBAD = <div/>;
<div/>;
```

The first `<div/>` will be assigned to `multiBAD`, the second one will be ignored.

This is not the problem in your code: in

```
const MultiElementWithFragments = 
<>
  ...
</>
```

the line

```
const MultiElementWithFragments =
```

is not a complete statement, so JavaScript will not try to insert the semicolon after it, and will recognise the fragment as belonging to the same statement. However, the common problem is with `return`:

```
return 
<>
  ...
</>
```

Here, `return` is a complete statement (equivalent to `return undefined`), the fragment is a complete statement, so JavaScript has no qualms about inserting the semicolon. It will be interpreted as

```
return undefined;
<>
  ...
</>
```

Note that you would have the same problem with

```
return
<div>
  ...
</div>
```

To avoid this, you can use the parentheses to make sure JavaScript understands that your statement is not finished:

```
return (
  <>
    ...
  </>
)
```

or

```
return (
  <div>
    ...
  <div/>
)
```

This will return a fragment and a div element, respectively.

Also, note that you do not need fragments in "multiline statements":

```
const hello =
<div>
  Please input your name:
  <input/>
</div>
```

This works fine without a fragment, even though there are more than one line — the important thing is that it is a single top-level element (`<div>`).

tl;dr: Parentheses and fragments, while both syntactically enclosing stuff, have very different purposes: fragments group *elements* into a data structure, while parentheses group *code* syntactically.